# JQuery - Bypass AJAX response once request is sent

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response

Im using the following way, to request PHP page to send mail to many users. I don't need the response at all. What I want is to just Call the function and start doing my thing in JS.

```
$.ajax({
  type    : 'POST',
  url     : 'mail_users.php',
  data    : formData,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  encode  : true
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("ERROR");
});
```

I also just want to make sure the request is done properly.
I tried many SO's suggestion like setTimeout() in JS and `ignore_user_abort(true)`, `set_time_limit(0)` in PHP.

But nothing worked for me,Is there any right snippet for this?.
How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? From a first view, it may be correct. It makes the request and the code should continue running no matter if the request was successful or not.

Comment: @Juan and all: Once the mail_users.php is requested (first AJAX request), I need to update table then reload the table section (which requires second AJAX request) in page. But the page is waiting for the (first AJAX request) process to complete before reloading the table section.

Comment: In that case, you should make the second call inside the "done" of the first one. The "done" section will be executed once the first call has been completed.

Comment: @Juan: That's what I want to overcome. My second AJAX call should not wait for the first AJAX call to complete. The second AJAX call should be called once the first AJAX call is made.

Comment: Then you just put the second call after the first. The first call should not stop execution of code.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to help. I wrote a code which make a AJAX call to a URL. It contains the callback functions but you can ignore (as you don't wanna check the result). Please, try this code changing the target URL.

**Result**

```
Tue Jun 21 2016 15:46:30 GMT-0300 (BRT) Req sent {"email_id":"1","key":"abc"}
Tue Jun 21 2016 15:46:30 GMT-0300 (BRT) Success
Tue Jun 21 2016 15:46:30 GMT-0300 (BRT) Complete {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\tResult:\n\t\t
\n\t\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

**Code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function log(msg) {
                var dateMsg = (new Date()) + ' ' + msg;
                var $res = $('#result');
                var $o = $('<li>').html(dateMsg);
                $res.append($o);
            }

            function checkEmailFrontEnd(email_id, key) {
                var userdata = {
                    email_id: email_id,
                    key: key
                };
                var opts = {
                    url: 'html.html',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: userdata,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        log('Success');
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
                        log('Error ' + error);
                    },
                    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                        log('Complete ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    }
                };
                $.ajax(opts);   
                log('Req sent ' + JSON.stringify(userdata));
            }
            $(function(){
                checkEmailFrontEnd('1', 'abc');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Result:
        <ul id='result'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here, .success() and .complete() takes time before requesting another $.ajax meanwhile.